# How can I update a lifecycle configuration with a filter based on both prefix and multiple tags in Ruby?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-ruby

I want to put a lifecycle_configuration to an S3 bucket with a rule that uses a filter with **multiple tags *and* a prefix**.

I can successfully `put_lifecycle_configuration` if the filter uses only one tag or one prefix, but I get a `Aws::S3::Errors::MalformedXML (The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema)` response from AWS if I try to use an `and:` to combine multiple tags or a tag and a prefix.

(edit: put the `prefix:...` within the `and:` Hash per [Ermiya's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69589070/661471) answer below)

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my rule:

```
aws_s3_backup_prefix = "production_backup" # this is fetched from ENV in real life

rule_expire_yearly_after_10y = {
        id: "Expire 1 January backups after 10 years",
        filter: {
          and: {
            prefix: aws_s3_backup_prefix,
            tags: [
              { key: 'date-month-day', value: '1'},
              { key: 'date-month-num', value: '1'}
            ]
          }
        },
        status: 'Enabled',
        expiration: {
          days: 3650
        }
      }
```

And here is how I use it to put the lifecycle configuration:

```
# aws_client is a valid Aws::S3::Client
# I have access to aws_s3_backup_bucket_name
# I can get and put a simple lifecycle_configuration (no 'and:') with this client and bucket

aws_client.put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration({
          bucket: aws_s3_backup_bucket_name,
          lifecycle_configuration: {
            rules: [ rule_expire_yearly_after_10y ]
          }
        })
```

**Config:**

- ruby 2.6.6
- aws-sdk-core 3.109.1
- aws-sdk-s3 1.103.0

[AWS Documentation: S3 User Guide: Examples of lifecycle configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-configuration-examples.html#lifecycle-config-ex1)

Comment: Yes, I can do that through the console (UI). And according to the SDK documentation, I should be able to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was fixed in the very next version.
I was using aws-sdk-core 3.109.1 and this was **fixed** in aws-sdk-core 3.109.2

Answer (score 0):

To specify a filter based on the key prefix *and* one or more tags, you need to place the `prefix` [*inside* of the `and` element](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/intro-lifecycle-rules.html#intro-lifecycle-rules-filter), not *outside*. Amazon S3 then can combine the prefix and tag filters.

This is why it's complaining about malformed XML.

This should apply the lifecycle rule to objects with a key prefix of `aws_s3_backup_prefix`, `date-month-day` tag value of 1 & `date-month-num` tag value of 1:

```
rule_expire_yearly_after_10y = {
  id: "Expire 1 January backups after 10 years",
  filter: {
    and: {
      prefix: aws_s3_backup_prefix,
      tags: [
        { key: 'date-month-day', value: '1'},
        { key: 'date-month-num', value: '1'}
      ]
    }
  },
  status: 'Enabled',
  expiration: {
    days: 3650
  }
}
```

Comment: Aha. You're right about that -- the prefix does belong within the `and:`  But it's still not working.  Still getting MalformedXML.  Does that rule work for you? (or at least not get a MalformedXML error)